# Padleft not adding leading zeros

Tags: c#, formatting, string-formatting

I added a `PadLeft(8,'0')` to my code to make sure that all accounts inserted into the database table were at least 8 characters long. Here is the code:

```
public static string CleanAccount(String strVal)
{
    string cleanValue;
    string paddedAccount = strVal.PadLeft(8,'0');
    //MessageBox.Show("account: " + paddedAccount);

    if (paddedAccount == null)
    {
        throw new System.ArgumentException("Value cannot be null", "original");
    }
    else
    {
        cleanValue = paddedAccount.Replace(" ", "").Replace("$", "").Replace("-", "");
    }

    return cleanValue;
}
```

---

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range xlRange = worksheet.UsedRange;

long fullRow = worksheet.Rows.Count;
long lastRow = worksheet.Cells[fullRow, 1].End(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row;
int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;

for (int i = 2; i <= lastRow; i++)
{
    lstTran.Add(new LegalTransactionRec()
                    {
                        AccountNumber = Form1.CleanAccount(xlRange.Cells[i, 1].Value2.ToString()),
                        CostAmount = Form1.CleanAmount(Form1.TryToParse(xlRange.Cells[i, 3].Value2.ToString())),
                        SSN = Form1.CleanString(xlRange.Cells[i, 6].Value2.ToString()),
                        TransactionDate = Form1.ConvertToDateTime(xlRange.Cells[i, 2].Value),
                        Description = Form1.CleanDescription(xlRange.Cells[i, 8].Value2.ToString()),
                        TransactionCode = Form1.CleanTranCode(Form1.CleanExtra(xlRange.Cells[i, 4].Value2.ToString()))
                    }
               );
}
```

When the `MessageBox` is not commented out I see that the account does get padded, but after it gets added into the database table it shows up without the leading zero. Any reason why this would happen?

Comment: why have you used `for (int j = 1; j <= 1; j++)` ? when `j <= 1` makes it useless and you are not using `j` inside the loop. you can remove it.

Comment: @WasifHossain Bandaid fix for the time being, I dont need to know what position the column is in.

Comment: I'll randomly guess that it has something to do with the type of a table column or the formatting of a spreadsheet cell.  Impossible to tell which.  So you see a number instead of a string and numbers don't have leading zeros.

Comment: @HansPassant You would be correct sir, silly me forgot to add single quotation marks around the item being added. Took a fresh set of eyes and me talking about it out loud to finally notice it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was a user one, and I found it out the same time Hans Passant mentioned it in the comments of the opening post.

Here is the change in my code:

```
sql.AppendLine(trans.AccountNumber + ",");
```

to

```
sql.AppendLine("'" + trans.AccountNumber + "',");
```